# Using Try Catch inside JUnit Test Case

Tags: java, junit4, mockmvc

Initially, I'm using **MockMvc** in Java Spring Boot Junit testcase. 
I'm sending a JSON with a message as Success *{"message": "Success"}*, if the message is not Success, without throwing an AssertionError Exception. It should check the message Failure statement which is under the catch block.

Without adding the catch block statement, Is there any feasible way to get Success,Failure scenario together. Below code explains what I have tried,

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    try {
        result = mockMvc.perform(post("/test/{testId}", "44")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"order\": \"desc\"}")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("message").value("Success"))
                .andReturn();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {

        result = mockMvc.perform(post("/test/{testId}", "44")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"order\": \"desc\"}")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("message").value("Failure"))
                .andReturn();

    }

}
```

Comment: You should really consider splitting those scenarios. It's good practice to have a test for each case / scenario

Comment: what is returned from the controller in case when it is not success?

Comment: It returns the JSON as follows, {
    "message": "Failure"
}

Comment: @MartínZaragoza In my scenario I have to PASS the test class even if the JSON returns Failure {"message": "Failure"}. Is there any possibility to put .andExpect statement after returning(.andReturn()) the (MvcResult) result

Comment: Martin is correct, split these up. why would posting the same request return success sometimes and failure other times? it's a unit test, you should have enough control for the inputs to specify the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 result = mockMvc.perform(post("/test/{testId}", "44")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"order\": \"desc\"}")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("message").value(org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.anyOf(is("Failure"), is("Success"))))
                .andReturn();
```

But I would suggest you try splitting these test cases into separate tests as Martin did.

Comment: Thank you @Pavel Bachyla, But unfortunately 'is' command is not working with MockMvc.

Comment: @Lakshan, I tried this option, and it worked well. Please, make sure we are using the same method: org.hamcrest.Matchers.is

Comment: I imported 'import org.hamcrest.core.Is', but I get the error as 'The method Is(String) is undefined for the type Test'

Comment: The guys are right. You'd better have two tests for two case.

Comment: The method is static, so that you need use 'static import': 
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

Comment: Thank you so much @PavelBachyla . It worked :) . Cheers.